# best practice ? should message display be service or directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am bit confused.

I know, I know ... anything that interacts with DOM should be created as directive. But somehow i feel more convenient just calling my notification service to either display error or success message which internally creates new div element and appends to the page and displays message and similarly removes the element when its done. More over i don't need to add html directive in page for the same. 
This is all working good but becomes little less testable (or i think so) and gives me guilty feeling of breaking the rules of directives and services.

Any good suggestion on this.

Comment: Definitely a directive . You don't have to create your own directive , usually there is something that will fit (maybe ng-show in your case) , and the logic can go in the controller (to show or not to show the message)

Comment: I use a combination of both for my custom message box.  I created a directive and put it on the root of my page, so I didn't have to include it in every view that wants to show a message.  Then I created a service that interacts with the message directive, with methods like  show() and error().  These methods take a config object which defines the title, message, button label(s) and action(s).

Comment: @CraigSquire you should provide an answer, I did the exact same thing as you describe.  I think it provides the separation of concerns that is needed between indicating there is a notification and responding in the DOM to that notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a combination of both for my custom message box. I created a message directive and put it on the root of my page, so I didn't have to include it in every view that wants to show a message. Then I created a service that interacts with the message directive, with methods like show() and error(). These methods take a config object which defines the title, message, button label(s) and action(s).

Comment: I thought of doing the same approach but does that bring two dependencies ... one on directive and one on service ... i agree but looks more complicated then it should be ... dont u agree .... ?

Comment: I assume you're asking about the directives that want to show a message.  No, there are not two dependencies, the only dependency is the service component.  The message directive will have the service injected and uses properties of the service to determine what it needs to do.