# Opening a view into a modal in AngularJS from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure if I am tackling this the right way..

I am starting an AngularJS app - first one, so trying to get my head around the architecture.

anyway. I have created a service `isAjax`, which uses the `$http` module and performs a call for me.

I am capturing the success/error responses.

this is my service - not sure if it's syntax is correct, though it works...

```
appServices.factory('isAjax', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

        var apiController = function (url) {
            if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
                return url.substring(url, url.indexOf('?'));
            } else {
                return url;
            }
        }

        var doHttp = function (url, method) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: method,
            url: url
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {

            switch (status) {

                // not found
                case 404:
                    bootbox.alert('api call to ' + apiController(url) + ' failed<br />URL does not exist');
                    break;

                // not authed - show login
                case 401:
                    // Here - I would like to somehow call a directive? which would open a bootstrap modal and load a view into it.
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log(arguments);
                    bootbox.alert('ajax error');
            }


            console.log(status);
            //alert('ERROR ON ISAjaxService');
            console.log('http errored')
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getData: function (url, method) {
            return doHttp(url, method);
        }
    }

}]);
```

I can call this service from anywhere by injecting `isAjax` and then calling:

```
var dataPromise = isAjax.getData('api/globaljson', 'get');
```

Now - where I have a status code `401` I would like to call something - i think a directive? - that would load a view into a modal and open it.

this is where I am stuck... If i create a directive, how do i interact with it from the service?

I could create a service to do it, though understand you're not supposed to do any kind of DOM manipulation in a service.

any help would be great.

thanks

Comment: I posted an answer on a similar question about showing a modal.  I would inject a "message service" and use it to trigger a modal directive that you put on the root of your page.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732720/best-practice-should-message-display-be-service-or-directive/21733818#21733818

Comment: In that case though, wouldn't I have a modal on the page with all my login markup in it? rather than loading a view into a modal - meaning i would only need one modal defined, then dynamically load whatever i like into it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a route for all the different navigations and route to that route if you get specific response ( just to say the route will load a external html and bind to a controller ). I personally use angular-route-segment library which adds more to the angular route library.
Please refer to
angular-route-segment.com for examples